# Inverse statement of hoelder-continuity for Hilbert curves

Tags: continuity, curves, holder-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

The [Hilbert-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) satisfies the [Hölder-condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition), thus defining [an upper limit](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000003494/2_kap2.pdf?hosts=) for the euclidian distance of two points in the plane in dependency of their distance on the Hilbert curve.

What I'm looking for is the inverse statement: Is there an upper limit for the distance of two points on the Hilbert curve given their distance on the plane?

After experimenting a little with [this widget](http://bit-player.org/extras/hilbert/hilbert-mapping.html) I assume that there is no such limit, but I wanted to ask somebody who really knows about this mathematical discipline.

[image: hilbert-experiments]

Comment: It's very unclear what kind of an upper bound you are looking for. For instance, would the bound $|x-y|\le 1$ be enough? (I do not think so.) Peano curves are necessarily non-injective, so you will have many points in the domain fixed distance apart whose images are equal.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for Holder continuity of a high-dimensional Hilbert curve? Thanks.